# Cannot appendChild to a custom web component

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component, native-web-component

I have a web-component at root level. The simplified version of which is shown below:

```js
class AppLayout {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.noShadow = true;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.render();
        this.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", this.navigation);
    }

    render() {
        this.innerHTML = this.template;
    }

    get template() {
        return `
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        `;
    }

    navigation = `
        <script type="module">
            import './components/nav-bar.js'
        </script>
    `;

}
customElements.define('app-layout', AppLayout);
```

I want to load a script after this component loads. The script creates html for navigation and tries to add it to the `app-layout` element shown above. However, even though, it does find the `app-layout` element, it is unable to append the `navBar` element. It is, however, able to append the `navBar` to the `body` of the html. Any ideas what I'm missing.

```
const navLinks =
    `<ul>
        <li>Some</li>
        <li>Links</li>
    </ul>
    `;

const navBar = document.createElement('nav');

navBar.innerHTML = navLinks;

const appLayout = document.querySelector('app-layout'); // works with 'body' but not with 'appLayout'
console.log(appLayout); // Logs correct element 
appLayout.appendChild(navBar);
```

I know that what I'm trying to do here (loading a script inside a web component) is not ideal, however, I would like to still understand why the above doesn't work.

Comment: Use the [<>] button in the editor, and make your code an executable SO snippet; we're not going to copy/paste your code by hand.

Answer (score 0):

using `innerHTML` or in your case `insertAdjacentHTML` to add `<script>` tags to the document doesn't work because browsers historically try to prevent potential cross site script attacks (https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)
What you could do is something like:

```js
const s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "module";
s.innerText = `import './components/nav-bar.js'`;
this.append(s);
// or simply directly without the script: `import('./comp..')` if it is really your only js in the script tag.
```